# Not showing up crashes in crashes & ANR Google developer console

Tags: android, crash, flurry, unhandled-exception

I have integrated with Flurry. Currently My app is on play store. In developer console it is only displaying only one crash. Where in Flurry it displays more crashes.

Would it happen that crashes will not show up on google developer console and show up in third party website?

Because I think if it shows up on Flurry errors then it should show up in Developer console in `Crashes & ANR` Menu.

Comment: Where are you printing ur crashes in google doc?

Comment: Actually I am not printing it anywhere. But it just shows up in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

When your app crashes, the user will get a dialog with the options "Force Close" or "Report."

[image: Force Close Dialog]

The user has to press the 'Report' option to send crash report to Developer Console, otherwise you may never know.

Whereas, Flurry automatically sends the crash report to its Server without asking permission from user.

That's why you see more crashes in Flurry and less in Developer Console.